# TSQL IN vs using Where with >= and <=

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have more than 10 fact tables. Each of them has has a Non-unique Clustered index `Id_Config_table`. Every data insert, an Id from Config_Table is being assigned to a fact table. Each `Id_Config_table` contains about 1-1.5 million rows of data.

**Config_Table**:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| Id | FactTbl   | Date     |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | FactTbl_1 | 20190101 |
| 2  | FactTbl_2 | 20190101 |
| 3  | FactTbl_1 | 20190101 |
| 4  | FactTbl_2 | 20190102 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Dates are not sorted in the above table, its sorted by Id.

My fact table looks like:

**Fact_Table_1**:

```
+------+---------------+-----------------+
| Col1 | few_more_cols | Id_Config_table |
+------+---------------+-----------------+
| ..   | ..            | 1               |
+------+---------------+-----------------+
| ..   | ..            | 3               |
+------+---------------+-----------------+
```

**Fact_Table_2**:

```
+------+---------------+-----------------+
| Col1 | few_more_cols | Id_Config_table |
+------+---------------+-----------------+
| ..   | ..            | 2               |
+------+---------------+-----------------+
| ..   | ..            | 4               |
+------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Currently, I am using this query:

```
Select 
    col1,
    few_more_cols 
from 
    Fact_Table_1
Where 
    Id_Config_table IN (Select Id  
                        from Config_Table 
                        where Date >= 20190101 and Date <= 20190331)
```

NOTE: Data in Fact_Table_1 or Fact_Table_2 are sorted using `Id_Config_table`, NOT by `Date` that is why I need to use a subquery. My fact tables contains 1 - 1.5 million rows of data for each `Id_Config_table`.

Now I am planning to add a new column which is Date in int format and make it the new clustered index. I can't remove the `Id_Config_table` column because its being used somewhere else.

**Fact_Table_new**:

```
+------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| Col1 | few_more_cols | Id_Config_table | Date     |
+------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| ..   | ..            | 8               | 20190101 |
| ..   | ..            | 7               | 20190102 |
| ..   | ..            | 1               | 20190103 |
+------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
```

In this case, data will be sorted by Date. I can now remove the subquery

```
Select 
    col1, few_more_cols 
from 
    Fact_Table_1
Where 
    Date >= 20190101 AND Date <= 20190331
```

Will it improve the query performance if I use the second query using the new index?

Comment: "Now I am planning to add a new column which is Date in int format" Don't. If you are adding a new column which is a Date, store it as `Date`, not as `int`.

Comment: May I know the reason why? I will only be using it as a filter for the where clause. Let me just be clear, it will be stored as a date (2019-01-01 but hypens were removed), not a unix timestamp.

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). This will cover much more than I can in a single comment.

Comment: Most likely the simpler query with appropriate index would perform better. You should simply try it and measure it yourself in your dev/test environment.

Comment: Might be I get this wrong, but this rather looks like an `INNER JOIN`. You can use both criteria with `AND` in the `ON` clause. About performance I'd suggest to read [Eric Lipper: Which is faster? or "race your horses"](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)